# How to set and get values of this form in local storage

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm setting up a local storage for settings form , and want to set and get each value of that form in local storage of  my application. What i need to add to make set and get correctly for this form?
everyone can see that the get results has error and mabe the set is not done correctly.
How to make all of that work 
do i need to change set and get methods? is there anythin that i am missing ? i tried all i know but i am a beginner in local storage and ionic .

my file ts :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm, FormControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EspaceAgentPage } from '../espace-agent/espace-agent';
import { EspaceCitoyenPage } from '../espace-citoyen/espace-citoyen';
import { ChangePasswordPage } from '../change-password/change-password';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { PasswordService } from '../services/password.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings',
  templateUrl: 'settings.html',
})
export class SettingsPage {
  private Form : FormGroup;
  public mail: any;
  public tel: any;
  public data: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastCtrl: ToastController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public storage: Storage)
  {
    this.Form = formBuilder.group({
      mailadress: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$'),Validators.email])],
      telephone: ['', Validators.compose([ Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(8)])],
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SettingsPage');
      this.getValue("stoker");
  }

  // set a key/value
  setValue(key: string, value: any)
  {
    this.storage.set(key, value).then((response) => {
      console.log('set' + key + ' ', response);

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('set error for ' + key + ' ', error);
    });
  }

  // get a key/value pair
    getValue(key: string) {
      this.storage.get(key).then((val) => {
        console.log('get ' + key + ' ', val);
        this.data[key] = "";
        this.data[key] = val;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('get error for ' + key + '', error);
      });
    }


  onChangepassword()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(ChangePasswordPage);
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm)
  {

    this.mail=this.Form.get('mailadress').value;
    this.tel=this.Form.get('telephone').value;
    console.log(form.value);
    this.setValue("stoker",this.mail);
    this.setValue("stoker",this.tel);

    this.navCtrl.push(EspaceCitoyenPage);
    const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Modifications Enregistrées !',
      duration: 4000
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

console results capture :

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Cay.png)

Comment: Please select an answer that was helpful in resolving the issue and [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you get the error in this funtion

```
// get a key/value pair
getValue(key: string) {
  this.storage.get(key).then((val) => {
    console.log('get ' + key + ' ', val);
    this.data[key] = "";
    this.data[key] = val;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('get error for ' + key + '', error);
  });
}
```

when you try to get stoker key returns a null reference and then the error. Maybe there is not item stored for this key or the palform was not ready when you call the storage.

When you work arround the storage you shoud wait from the platform to be ready like this:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

-----

constructor(private storage: NativeStorage, private plt: Platform) {}

  this.plt.ready().then(() => {
     // call native storage
  });
```

And think is better use Native Storage than ionic storage.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

plsease refer [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage)

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) { }
```

```js
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) { }
 
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );

this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );

this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
localstorage.setitem('your key as your wish',your value),
```

all storage value are stored in string
ex;-

```
localstorage.setitem('key', value)
localstorage.getitem('key')
```

You can use

```
Windows.localstorage.setitem('key', value)
```

Comment: You might mean `localStorage`